# How to connect to wifi on Lubuntu

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I am a Windows user, I installed Lubuntu in my old system since it has low RAM (1GB) . I cannot connect to wi-fi using 802.11n realtek dongle. In command window it shows device status:down. I do not have access to wired net.
Please help

Result of `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 03f0:0024 Hewlett-Packard KU-0316 Keyboard 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Operating System Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
```

Comment: With the dongle attached to USB, open up a terminal and give the command `lsusb` and post the output.

Comment: What documentation have you tried to follow and where did you get stuck?  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide etc.   Providing your release of Lubuntu is also helpful.   If using Lubuntu 18.10 the online manual can be read at https://manual.lubuntu.me/ but please note main Ubuntu documentation is where I'd suggest starting.

Comment: lsusb result:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 03f0:0024 Hewlett-Packard KU-0316 Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Operating System
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: also it shows exclamation mark beside the wifi icon

sorry for bad formatting

Comment: From the output of `lsusb`, your realtek dongle (wi-fi 802.11n) is listed as `Device 003`. @Semicolon, did you try to install your dongle on Lubuntu? Unless Windows, Wi-Fi dongle is not `Plug and Play` on Ubuntu. You need to install it! Did you attempt to install? Please supply more details.